# How do I remove content between X and Y using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

What would the regular expression be for removing any content between a quote, and the directory "uploads/"?

Using a regexpression generator, I get this: (?<=\=")[^]+?(?=uploads/)

```
$block_data = preg_replace('/(?<=\=")[^]+?(?=uploads/)/g','',$block_data);
```

But seems to be removing everything :(

Comment: Can you give an example for the input?

Comment: Instead of a regex generator, I would use a regex checker such as  the one at [bokehman](http://bokehman.com/regex_checker) (my favorite), or [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), or [spaweditor](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/) (for PHP) or [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx). That way you'll learn to write them yourself and you won't need a generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the "/" in "uploads/" and `g` isn't a valid modifier, plus `[^]` is invalid, I guess you wanted `.` instead.

Here is your regex :

```
/(?<=\=").+?(?=uploads\/)/
```

The test on [ideone](http://ideone.com/acmT4)

Comment: Thanks Colin, this was working until I noticed one thing I've been trying to figure out. If there are multiple images/links I need to do this to on the same line, it looks like it grabs everything from the very first quote, to the very last uploads/ pathname. ie:

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be

```
$block_data = preg_replace('/(?<=").*?(?=uploads\/)/','',$block_data);
```

Changes made:

1. Simplified your lookbehind and lookahead assertions
2. escaped the `/` in the lookahead
3. removed the `g` modifier, which is unnecessary in PHP

This works, so far as I can tell, reducing `first"middle/uploads/end"` to `first"uploads/end"`.

Comment: By simplifying you remove the "=" part in the look-behind (which could be important) and you removed the laziness (which could be dangerous) and replaced it by an optional `.` (which is wrong given the initial regex).

Comment: @Colin the spec is "after a quote" (hence the lookbehind change) and "any content" (hence the change to `.*`).  I had already changed the greedy `*`.